# openstack installation using conjure up stuck with waiting for machine status

Tags: conjure-up

[image: screenshot]

The configuration of the machine used to install openstack is
virtual machine with 20 GB RAM dual Intel Xeon processor(16 cores each), 60 GB HDD free space. OS- Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64 bit.
Using, conjure-up, initiated installation, installed lxd using sudo apt-get install lxd, sudo apt-get install lxd-client. default values has been used for the ip and bridge configuration of lxd. 
The installation of openstack stuck at deployment watcher with waiting for machine status(screenshot attached for reference). What might be the issue. Kindly help to solve the issue.

Thanks
Bhupendra